# CSS drop-down menu not working when I hover over link

Tags: html, css

I have spent the past few hours of my life trying to get this drop down menu to work to no avail.  I'm trying to to make the list menu `.dropdown` appear when you hover over `.droptoggle`. I'm just going to show the whole page because I have no idea what it could be, knowing me its probably the smallest and easiest thing to fix. (I am very new to html and css so this will probably look very messy. Thanks a lot for any help!

Html:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #36363c;
}

.tbback {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2d2d33;
}

.navtext li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navtext a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.navtext a:hover {
  color: #712889;
}

.navtext {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navtext i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.openapi {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.openapi i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.openapi:hover {
  color: #30ee46;
}

.chatback {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  width: 300px;
  background: #2d2d33;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  float: left;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #44444b;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #494950;
}

.chatobject {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 15px;
}

.droptoggle {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.imground {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #ff54489c;
  z-index: 15;
}

.fas.fa-caret-down {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 13px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.profilename {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
}

.userprop {
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
}

.userprop li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.userprop i {
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.userprop a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.proppos {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 250px;
}

.userprop a:hover {
  color: #ff5448;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #2d2d33;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown i {
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.droptoggle:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<?

    require 'steamauth/steamauth.php';
    require 'steamauth/userInfo.php';

    if(isset($_SESSION['steamid']))
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['steamid'];
    }

    else
    {
        #Not logged in
    }
?>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LoopTrades</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Teko:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/80f97a33ce.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<!--Start of Tawk.to Script-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {}, Tawk_LoadStart = new Date();
    (function () {
        var s1 = document.createElement("script"), s0 = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s1.async = true;
        s1.src = 'https://embed.tawk.to/60fab213d6e7610a49aca619/1fb9kf738';
        s1.charset = 'UTF-8';
        s1.setAttribute('crossorigin', '*');
        s0.parentNode.insertBefore(s1, s0);
    })();
</script>
<!--End of Tawk.to Script-->
<body>

<!---NAVBAR--->
    <? if(isset($_SESSION['steamid'])) {?>
<div class="tbback">
    <div class="proppos">
        <ul class="userprop">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>DEPOSIT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i>INVENTORY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="droptoggle"><img class="imground" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatarmedium'];?>"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="navtext">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>TRADE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/premium.html" style="color: #ffe063;"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>PREMIUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>GIVEAWAYS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #ff5448;"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><?=$steamprofile['personaname'];?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>Rewards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <!---DEPO--->
    <!---CHAT--->
 <div class="chatback">
    <div class="chatscroll">
        <div class="chatobject">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<? } else {?>

<? } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.dropdown` must be as a next sibling of `.droptoggle` Right now they have two different parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `.dropdown` element right after `.droptoggle`:

```
<div class="tbback">
    <div class="proppos">
        <ul class="userprop">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>DEPOSIT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i>INVENTORY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="navtext">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>TRADE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/premium.html" style="color: #ffe063;"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>PREMIUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>GIVEAWAYS</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" class="droptoggle"><img class="imground" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatarmedium'];?>"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: #ff5448;"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><?=$steamprofile['personaname'];?></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>Rewards</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and than fix it with this css:

```
.droptoggle {
/*
  float: right;
  display: flex;
*/
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.dropdown:hover,
.droptoggle:hover + .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the following CSS selector:

```
.droptoggle:hover + .dropdown
```

This selector selects any element with class .dropdown which comes directly after an element with class .droptoggle on the same hierarchy level.

But your .dropdown list element is not on the same level:

```
<div class="tbback">
    <a href="#" class="droptoggle">(...)</a>
    (...)
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        (...)
    </ul>
</div>
```

So one of multiple possible solutions can be to move your .dropdown div element inside the .tbback element right after the .navtext ul element and change your CSS selector to:

```
.droptoggle:hover + .navtext + .dropdown
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #36363c;
}

.tbback {
  height: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2d2d33;
}

.navtext li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 25px;
}

.navtext a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.navtext a:hover {
  color: #712889;
}

.navtext {
  text-align: center;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.navtext i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.openapi {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 21px;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.openapi i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.openapi:hover {
  color: #30ee46;
}

.chatback {
  height: calc(100vh - 65px);
  width: 300px;
  background: #2d2d33;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  float: left;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #44444b;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #494950;
}

.chatobject {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Source Code Pro", monospace;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 15px;
}

.droptoggle {
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 13px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.imground {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 3px solid #ff54489c;
  z-index: 15;
}

.fas.fa-caret-down {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding-top: 13px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
}

.profilename {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #cfcfcf;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: large;
}

.userprop {
  padding-top: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 11;
}

.userprop li {
  display: inline;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.userprop i {
  padding-right: 4px;
}

.userprop a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #a8a8a8;
  font-family: "Teko", sans-serif;
  font-size: medium;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
}

.proppos {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 250px;
}

.userprop a:hover {
  color: #ff5448;
}

.dropdown {
  
  margin-top: 5px;
  background: #2d2d33;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left:20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.dropdown a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Cairo", sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.dropdown i {
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.testing:hover > .dropdown {
  display: block;
  
}
.testing{
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="tbback">
    <div class="proppos">
        <ul class="userprop">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-wallet"></i>DEPOSIT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-suitcase"></i>INVENTORY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  <div class="testing">
    <a href="#" class="droptoggle"><img class="imground" src="<?=$steamprofile['avatarmedium'];?>"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #ff5448;"><i class="fas fa-user"></i><?=$steamprofile['personaname'];?></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>Rewards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i>Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i>Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="steamauth/logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
    </div>
    
    <ul class="navtext">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-sync-alt"></i>TRADE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>SHOP</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/premium.html" style="color: #ffe063;"><i class="fas fa-crown"></i>PREMIUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" style="color: #30ee46;"><i class="fas fa-gift"></i>GIVEAWAYS</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

    <!---DEPO--->
    <!---CHAT--->
 <div class="chatback">
    <div class="chatscroll">
        <div class="chatobject">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```